# Need help for displaying table dynamically

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a lightning component where I am passing object name and API names as parameters. I want to display a table based on the parameters and the table should be dynamic. I have developed the below logic but I am not getting the result as expected. Can someone help me fix the issue since I new to lightning components...

**Apex Logic**

```
public class GenericObjectController {
    @auraEnabled
    public static List<String> fetchFieldLabels(String apiNames, String objName) {
        List<String> fieldLabels = new List<String>();
        List<String> apis = (List<String>)JSON.deserialize(apiNames, List<String>.class);
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        for(String eachAPI : apis) {
            fieldLabels.add(fieldMap.get(eachAPI).getDescribe().getLabel());
        }
        return fieldLabels;
    }
    @auraEnabled
    public static Map<String,List<Object>> fetchObjectRecs(String objName, String orderBy, String apiNames) {
        Map<String,List<Object>> valueMap = new Map<String,List<Object>>();
        List<String> fieldLabels = new List<String>();
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        List<String> apis = (List<String>) JSON.deserialize(apiNames, List<String>.class);
        for(String eachAPI : apis) {
            fieldLabels.add(fieldMap.get(eachAPI).getDescribe().getName());
        }
        String query = 'SELECT ' + String.join(apis, ',') + ' FROM ' + objName + ' ORDER BY ' + orderBy + ' ASC LIMIT 10';
        List<sObject> queryResult = Database.query(query);
        for(String fieldLabel : fieldLabels) {
            for(sObject eachRecord : queryResult) {
                if(valueMap.containsKey(fieldLabel)) {
                    valueMap.get(fieldLabel).add(eachRecord.get(fieldLabel));
                }
                else 
                    valueMap.put(fieldLabel,new List<object>{eachRecord.get(fieldLabel)});
            }
        }
        System.debug('::Fields::'+fieldLabels);
        System.debug('::Query::'+queryResult);
        System.debug('::Keys::'+valueMap.keySet());
        System.debug('::Values::'+valueMap.Values());
        return valueMap;
        
    }
}
```

**Lightning Component**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="GenericObjectController">
    <aura:attribute name="objectName" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="apiNames" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="orderBy" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="objectDetails" type="Object[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fieldNames" type="String"/>
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    
    <div class="slds-m-around_x-large">
        <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped">
            <thead>
                <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.fieldNames}" var="obj">
                        <th>{!obj}</th>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.objectDetails}" var="mapKey" indexVar="key">
                    <tr>
                        <aura:iteration items="{!mapKey.value}" var="mapValue">
                            <td>{!mapValue}</td>
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**.controllerJS**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.fetchFieldLabels");
        action.setParams({
            "apiNames" : JSON.stringify(component.get("v.apiNames")),
            "objName" : component.get("v.objectName")
        });
        console.log("::APINames::",JSON.stringify(component.get("v.apiNames")));
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            console.log("::State::",state);
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                var result = response.getReturnValue();
                console.log("::Response::",JSON.stringify(result));
                component.set("v.fieldNames",result);
            }
        });
        var getRecords = component.get("c.fetchObjectRecs");
        getRecords.setParams({
            "objName" : component.get("v.objectName"),
            "orderBy" : component.get("v.orderBy"),
            "apiNames" : JSON.stringify(component.get("v.apiNames"))
        });
        getRecords.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                var result = response.getReturnValue();
                var mapData = [];
                for(var key in result) {
                    mapData.push({key : key, value : result[key] });
                }
                console.log("Map",mapData);
                component.set("v.objectDetails",mapData);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        $A.enqueueAction(getRecords);
    }
})
```

Thanks in Advance...

[image]

Comment: Where exactly you are facing the issue? It would be great if you could explain where you need help, instead of posting the whole code. :)

Comment: In the image I have posted I am getting record values in row wise instead of column wise. I was not able to fix that issue. I thought the issue with aura:iteration. Can you help me how to fix that. Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend switching to lightninig:datatable instead of HTML table and below is the code for it.

Apex:

```
public class GenericObjectController {
    
    @auraEnabled
    public static Map<String,String> fetchFieldLabels(String apiNames, String objName) {
        List<String> fieldLabels = new List<String>();
        Map<String,String> fieldLabelsMap = new Map<String,String>();
        List<String> apis = (List<String>)JSON.deserialize(apiNames, List<String>.class);
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        for(String eachAPI : apis) {
            fieldLabelsMap.put(fieldMap.get(eachAPI).getDescribe().getLabel(),eachAPI);
        }
        return fieldLabelsMap;
    }
    @auraEnabled
    public static List<sObject> fetchObjectRecs(String objName, String orderBy, String apiNames) {
        Map<String,List<Object>> valueMap = new Map<String,List<Object>>();
        List<String> fieldLabels = new List<String>();
        Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        List<String> apis = (List<String>) JSON.deserialize(apiNames, List<String>.class);
        for(String eachAPI : apis) {
            fieldLabels.add(fieldMap.get(eachAPI).getDescribe().getName());
        }
        String query = 'SELECT ' + String.join(apis, ',') + ' FROM ' + objName + ' ORDER BY ' + orderBy + ' ASC LIMIT 10';
        List<sObject> queryResult = Database.query(query);
        return queryResult;
    }
}
```

Aura component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" controller="GenericObjectController">
    <aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="apiNames" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="orderBy" default="Name" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="objectDetails" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fieldNames" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.objectDetails.length > 0}">
        <lightning:datatable keyField="id"
                             data="{! v.objectDetails }"
                             columns="{! v.columns }"
                             hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
    </aura:if>
    
</aura:component>
```

Aura controller.js:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.fetchFieldLabels");
        action.setParams({
            "apiNames" : JSON.stringify(component.get("v.apiNames")),
            "objName" : component.get("v.sObjectName")
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                var result = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.fieldNames", result);
                let objArr = [];               
                for(var key in result) {
                    let newObj = new Object;
                    newObj["label"] = key;
                    newObj["fieldName"] = result[key];
                    objArr.push(newObj);
                }
                component.set('v.columns', objArr);
            }
        });
        var getRecords = component.get("c.fetchObjectRecs");
        getRecords.setParams({
            "objName" : component.get("v.sObjectName"),
            "orderBy" : component.get("v.orderBy"),
            "apiNames" : JSON.stringify(component.get("v.apiNames"))
        });
        getRecords.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                var result = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.objectDetails",result);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        $A.enqueueAction(getRecords);
    }
})
```

and the result will be like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have modified the code according to your response. Can you suggest me any way to get the same using html table. Thanks..

Comment: @SaiVineeth refer this post, https://www.infallibletechie.com/2018/02/auraiteration-example-in-salesforce.html